# Twitter API: What is the difference in the following URLs?

Tags: twitter

What is going on in the following?

```
import json, urllib
url = "funnyfurniture.net/p/10/oops-chair/"
url2 = "http://funnyfurniture.net/p/10/oops-chair/"
tw_url = "http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=%s" %url
tw_url2 = "http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=%s" %url2
js2 = json.load(urllib.urlopen(tw_url))
js = json.load(urllib.urlopen(tw_url2))
print js2, js
```

It gives

```
{u'count': 0, u'url': u'http://funnyfurniture.net/p/10/oops-chair/'} {u'count': 1, u'url': u'http://funnyfurniture.net/p/10/oops-chair/'}
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Strange. Both queries are showing same number now... Not sure why...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Twitter API normalizes URLs, so when you pass in `cnn.com` it converts it to `http://cnn.com` automatically:

```
% curl 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=foo'
{"count":0,"url":"http://foo/"}
```

The discrepancy in the counts you saw may have been a temporary bug on Twitter's side, e.g., calculating the counts before normalizing the URLs.

Comment: Looks like this has since been fixed; I'm now getting a count of 1 for both `js2` and `js`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Twitter infrastructure is in the cloud, it might be as a replication data "error". It is not being synchronized well in all nodes.